# Fetch 10 paginated ranked posts of each category

Tags: postgresql, rank

Posts table as p:

```
| id | cid | score | ...
--------------------
|  1 |  1  |   3   | ...
```

Categories Table as c:

```
| id |...
--------------------
|  1 |...
```

What i need? Reterive paginated ranked posts in each category.

What i did do:

```
SELECT
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (
    PARTITION BY c.id
    ORDER BY p."score" DESC NULLS LAST) AS ranking,
    p.id,
    count(*) OVER() AS full_count
FROM p                              
INNER JOIN c ON c.id=p.cid
offset 20 limit 10
```

This query will return whole records and affect offset/limit on it. But i need to affect offset/limit on each category, separated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Akina suggested, add [`row_number()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) and filter on the next query level:

```
SELECT ranking, id, full_count
FROM  (
   SELECT dense_rank() OVER w  AS ranking
        , p.id
        , count(*)     OVER () AS full_count
        , row_number() OVER w  AS rn
   FROM   p                              
   -- JOIN   c ON c.id = p.cid
   WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY p.cid ORDER BY p.score DESC NULLS LAST)
   ) sub
WHERE rn BETWEEN 21 AND 30;
```

This return row 21 to 30 *per window* (per `pid`) - no rows if there are less than 21.

A subquery is typically faster than a CTE in Postgres (at least up to version 11). Only use CTEs where *needed*.

Also, if referential integrity is enforced with a foreign key constraint, the join to `c` adds nothing but cost. Drop it.

And since we are reusing the same window definition twice, a `WINDOW` clause avoids spelling it out repeatedly (no effect on performance, though).

That `full_count` looks odd. If you need the full count *per window*, make that `count(*) OVER w` as well.

#### Alternative for *few* groups

For a small number of groups (few distinct `pid`), a [`LATERAL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) join with index support is typically ***faster***:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM   c
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY p.score DESC NULLS LAST) AS ranking
        , p.id
        , count(*) OVER () AS full_count_per_window
   FROM   p                              
   WHERE  p.cid = c.id
   ORDER  BY p.score DESC NULLS LAST
   OFFSET 20
   LIMIT  10
   ) p
-- WHERE c.* ... -- some filter on c?
```

This time with a full count *per window*.
"Index support" would ideally be:

```
CREATE INDEX ON p (pid, score DESC NULLS LAST);
```

`score DESC NULLS LAST` is the perfect inversion of `score ASC`, so a simpler index on `(pid, score)` is also applicable using index scan backwards. See:

- [PostgreSQL sort by datetime asc, null first?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9511492/939860)

About that `LATERAL` join:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25536748/939860)
- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28557803/939860)

Generally, `OFFSET` is a poor tools for **pagination**. See:

- [What is the recommended way to join junction tables for efficient ordering/pagination?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/205268/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-join-junction-tables-for-efficient-ordering-pagin/205286#205286)
- [Efficient pagination for big tables](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/219782/efficient-pagination-for-big-tables/219810#219810)