# Fastest way to choose distinct rows and a different order by without using a subquery

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

**PostgresSQL - Join and get distinct left table rows only without gigantic subquery sort**

We have a midsized database that has 50k rows of products and 33m rows of product prices at various store locations.

We join the products table to the access table with various where conditions / order by the suit the end user the best.

A simple explanation of a typical query would be 100 distinct products, sorted by highest price first, sorted by in stock first.

Seems simple enough... Everything I read online says to join the tables with a LEFT INNER JOIN (perhaps this is the wrong type of join to get unique rows?) on products_displayproductaccess in a sub query, then order the outer query by the order we're looking for. Problem is the performance is brutal... We partitioned the tables and it did help, but not significantly due the large sort size.

I'm surprised this is such an issue in Postgres (or perhaps other DB's as well) or the solution has just alluded me and the other upwork DBA's we've paid. It's just a join to get unique rows from the left table...

**products_displayproduct**

```
Table "public.products_displayproduct"
        Column         |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |                       Default                       | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
-----------------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id                    | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('products_displayproduct_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 date_created          | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |                                                     | plain    |              | 
 date_updated          | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |                                                     | plain    |              | 
 name                  | character varying(255)   |           | not null |                                                     | extended |              | 
 sub_title             | character varying(255)   |           |          |                                                     | extended |              | 
 tags                  | character varying(255)   |           |          |                                                     | extended |              | 
 has_multiple_variants | boolean                  |           | not null |                                                     | plain    |              | 
 rating                | numeric(3,2)             |           | not null |                                                     | main     |              | 
 reviews               | integer                  |           | not null |                                                     | plain    |              | 
 is_toppick            | boolean                  |           | not null |                                                     | plain    |              | 
 search_index          | tsvector                 |           | not null |                                                     | extended |              | 
 brand_id              | integer                  |           |          |                                                     | plain    |              | 
 placement_id          | integer                  |           | not null |                                                     | plain    |              | 
 poster_image_id       | integer                  |           |          |                                                     | plain    |              | 
 last_amalgamation     | timestamp with time zone |           |          |                                                     | plain    |              | 
Indexes:
    "products_displayproduct_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "products_di_id_f3063a_idx" btree (id, placement_id)
    "products_di_search__a06b26_gist" gist (search_index)
    "products_displayproduct_brand_id_c215ec11" btree (brand_id)
    "products_displayproduct_is_toppick_3901660d" btree (is_toppick)
    "products_displayproduct_last_amalgamation_bcfdab2f" btree (last_amalgamation)
    "products_displayproduct_name_6e5686c5" btree (name)
    "products_displayproduct_name_6e5686c5_like" btree (name varchar_pattern_ops)
    "products_displayproduct_name_gist" gist (name gist_trgm_ops)
    "products_displayproduct_placement_id_90f0d4a2" btree (placement_id)
    "products_displayproduct_poster_image_id_7c188e4d" btree (poster_image_id)
    "products_displayproduct_rating_98794c10" btree (rating)
    "products_displayproduct_reviews_4d5513bb" btree (reviews)
    "products_displayproduct_sub_title_72354226" btree (sub_title)
    "products_displayproduct_sub_title_72354226_like" btree (sub_title varchar_pattern_ops)
    "products_displayproduct_tags_ab900c6b" btree (tags)
    "products_displayproduct_tags_ab900c6b_like" btree (tags varchar_pattern_ops)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "products_displayprod_brand_id_c215ec11_fk_products_" FOREIGN KEY (brand_id) REFERENCES products_displaybrand(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "products_displayprod_placement_id_90f0d4a2_fk_retailers" FOREIGN KEY (placement_id) REFERENCES retailers_displaysubcategory(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "products_displayprod_poster_image_id_7c188e4d_fk_products_" FOREIGN KEY (poster_image_id) REFERENCES products_displayproductimage(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
Referenced by:
    TABLE "intake_intakeproduct" CONSTRAINT "intake_intakeproduct_displayed_as_id_479d7ed0_fk_products_" FOREIGN KEY (displayed_as_id) REFERENCES products_displayproduct(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    TABLE "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct" CONSTRAINT "products_amalgamated_orig_product_id_df68bcd8_fk_products_" FOREIGN KEY (orig_product_id) REFERENCES products_displayproduct(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    TABLE "products_displayproductvariant" CONSTRAINT "products_displayprod_product_id_210696e5_fk_products_" FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products_displayproduct(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    TABLE "products_displayproductaccess" CONSTRAINT "products_displayprod_product_id_2a2032ac_fk_products_" FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products_displayproduct(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    TABLE "reviews_displayproductreview" CONSTRAINT "reviews_displayprodu_product_id_1d59703e_fk_products_" FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products_displayproduct(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    TABLE "search_searchquery" CONSTRAINT "search_searchquery_from_product_id_8f9dfd22_fk_products_" FOREIGN KEY (from_product_id) REFERENCES products_displayproduct(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

**products_displayproductaccess**

```
       Column       |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |                          Default                          | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
--------------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id                 | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('products_displayproductaccess_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 date_created       | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |                                                           | plain    |              | 
 date_updated       | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |                                                           | plain    |              | 
 price              | numeric(16,2)            |           | not null |                                                           | main     |              | 
 quantity           | smallint                 |           | not null |                                                           | plain    |              | 
 department         | character varying(64)    |           |          |                                                           | extended |              | 
 aisle              | character varying(64)    |           |          |                                                           | extended |              | 
 original_price     | numeric(16,2)            |           |          |                                                           | main     |              | 
 is_onsale          | boolean                  |           | not null |                                                           | plain    |              | 
 is_instock         | boolean                  |           | not null |                                                           | plain    |              | 
 sale_until         | date                     |           |          |                                                           | plain    |              | 
 sale_percent       | numeric(5,2)             |           | not null |                                                           | main     |              | 
 sale_amount        | numeric(16,2)            |           | not null |                                                           | main     |              | 
 location_id        | integer                  |           | not null |                                                           | plain    |              | 
 product_variant_id | integer                  |           | not null |                                                           | plain    |              | 
 retailer_id        | integer                  |           | not null |                                                           | plain    |              | 
 product_id         | integer                  |           |          |                                                           | plain    |              | 
 location_intspace  | integer                  |           | not null |                                                           | plain    |              | 
Indexes:
    "products_displayproductaccess_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "pmtest" btree (location_intspace, location_id) INCLUDE (product_id, price, is_instock)
    "products_displayproductaccess_aisle_61457682" btree (aisle)
    "products_displayproductaccess_aisle_61457682_like" btree (aisle varchar_pattern_ops)
    "products_displayproductaccess_date_created_d38d9b4e" btree (date_created)
    "products_displayproductaccess_date_updated_0c689801" btree (date_updated)
    "products_displayproductaccess_department_a7031553" btree (department)
    "products_displayproductaccess_department_a7031553_like" btree (department varchar_pattern_ops)
    "products_displayproductaccess_idx_highest_priced" btree (product_id, price DESC, is_instock DESC)
    "products_displayproductaccess_is_instock_d5c2eef0" btree (is_instock)
    "products_displayproductaccess_is_onsale_bdc85585" btree (is_onsale)
    "products_displayproductaccess_location_id_fe5aeb43" btree (location_id)
    "products_displayproductaccess_original_price_904da60f" btree (original_price)
    "products_displayproductaccess_price_0e2f3286" btree (price)
    "products_displayproductaccess_product_id_2a2032ac" btree (product_id)
    "products_displayproductaccess_product_variant_id_ab7b9896" btree (product_variant_id)
    "products_displayproductaccess_quantity_72b1a17c" btree (quantity)
    "products_displayproductaccess_retailer_id_70041027" btree (retailer_id)
    "products_displayproductaccess_sale_amount_6cf01b14" btree (sale_amount)
    "products_displayproductaccess_sale_percent_5f469f10" btree (sale_percent)
    "products_displayproductaccess_sale_until_afb569bf" btree (sale_until)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "products_displayprod_location_id_fe5aeb43_fk_retailers" FOREIGN KEY (location_id) REFERENCES retailers_baselocation(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "products_displayprod_product_id_2a2032ac_fk_products_" FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products_displayproduct(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "products_displayprod_product_variant_id_ab7b9896_fk_products_" FOREIGN KEY (product_variant_id) REFERENCES products_displayproductvariant(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "products_displayprod_retailer_id_70041027_fk_retailers" FOREIGN KEY (retailer_id) REFERENCES retailers_retailer(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
Triggers:
    after_insert_products_displayproductaccess_trigger AFTER INSERT ON products_displayproductaccess FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE products_displayproductaccess_delete_master()
    before_insert_products_displayproductaccess_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON products_displayproductaccess FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE products_displayproductaccess_insert_child()
Child tables: products_displayproductaccess_745_745,
              products_displayproductaccess_746_746,
              products_displayproductaccess_747_747,
              products_displayproductaccess_748_748,
              products_displayproductaccess_749_749,
              products_displayproductaccess_750_750,
              products_displayproductaccess_751_751,
              products_displayproductaccess_752_752,
              products_displayproductaccess_753_753,
              products_displayproductaccess_754_754,
              products_displayproductaccess_755_755,
              products_displayproductaccess_756_756,
              products_displayproductaccess_757_757,
              products_displayproductaccess_758_758,
              products_displayproductaccess_759_759,
              products_displayproductaccess_760_760,
              products_displayproductaccess_761_761,
              products_displayproductaccess_762_762,
              products_displayproductaccess_763_763,
              products_displayproductaccess_764_764,
              products_displayproductaccess_765_765,
              products_displayproductaccess_766_766,
              products_displayproductaccess_767_767,
              products_displayproductaccess_768_768,
              products_displayproductaccess_769_769,
              products_displayproductaccess_770_770,
              products_displayproductaccess_771_771,
              products_displayproductaccess_772_772,
              products_displayproductaccess_773_773,
              products_displayproductaccess_774_774,
              products_displayproductaccess_775_775,
              products_displayproductaccess_776_776,
              products_displayproductaccess_777_777,
              products_displayproductaccess_778_778,
              products_displayproductaccess_779_779,
              products_displayproductaccess_780_780,
              products_displayproductaccess_781_781,
              products_displayproductaccess_782_782,
              products_displayproductaccess_783_783,
              products_displayproductaccess_784_784,
              products_displayproductaccess_785_785,
              products_displayproductaccess_786_786,
              products_displayproductaccess_787_787,
              products_displayproductaccess_788_788,
              products_displayproductaccess_789_789,
              products_displayproductaccess_790_790,
              products_displayproductaccess_791_791,
              products_displayproductaccess_792_792,
              products_displayproductaccess_793_793,
              products_displayproductaccess_794_794,
              products_displayproductaccess_795_795,
              products_displayproductaccess_796_796,
              products_displayproductaccess_797_797,
              products_displayproductaccess_798_798,
              products_displayproductaccess_799_799,
              products_displayproductaccess_801_801,
              products_displayproductaccess_802_802,
              products_displayproductaccess_803_803,
              products_displayproductaccess_805_805,
              products_displayproductaccess_806_806,
              products_displayproductaccess_807_807,
              products_displayproductaccess_808_808,
              products_displayproductaccess_809_809,
              products_displayproductaccess_810_810,
              products_displayproductaccess_811_811,
              products_displayproductaccess_812_812,
              products_displayproductaccess_814_814,
              products_displayproductaccess_816_816,
              products_displayproductaccess_818_818,
              products_displayproductaccess_819_819,
              products_displayproductaccess_821_821,
              products_displayproductaccess_822_822,
              products_displayproductaccess_824_824,
              products_displayproductaccess_827_827,
              products_displayproductaccess_837_837,
              products_displayproductaccess_849_849,
              products_displayproductaccess_859_859
```

**Attempt #1 (right results - wrong execution time) - using subquery and distinct. The performance is brutal because postgres will find all the matching rows from the index first, then do a sort on those entries which is can be millions of rows**

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
      DISTINCT ON (
          "products_displayproductaccess"."product_id"
      ) 
      "products_displayproduct"."id", 
      "products_displayproduct"."date_created", 
      "products_displayproduct"."date_updated", 
      "products_displayproduct"."name", 
      "products_displayproduct"."sub_title", 
      "products_displayproduct"."tags", 
      "products_displayproduct"."has_multiple_variants", 
      "products_displayproduct"."placement_id", 
      "products_displayproduct"."brand_id", 
      "products_displayproduct"."poster_image_id", 
      "products_displayproduct"."rating", 
      "products_displayproduct"."reviews", 
      "products_displayproduct"."is_toppick", 
      "products_displayproduct"."last_amalgamation", 
      "products_displayproduct"."search_index",
      "products_displayproductaccess"."price",
      "products_displayproductaccess"."is_instock"
    FROM 
      "products_displayproduct" 
      INNER JOIN "products_displayproductaccess" ON (
        "products_displayproduct"."id" = "products_displayproductaccess"."product_id"
      ) 
    WHERE 
      (
        --"products_displayproduct"."placement_id" = 853
        "products_displayproductaccess"."location_intspace" IN (755)
        AND "products_displayproductaccess"."location_id" IN (
         55,
         60,
         61,
         62,
         64,
         65,
         68,
         69,
         72,
         78,
         79,
         81,
         84,
         85,
         89,
         92,
         97,
         99,
         101,
         102,
         113,
         120,
         121,
         130,
         149,
         187,
         210,
         234,
         597,
         599,
         601,
         602,
         603,
         605,
         606,
         607,
         608,
         610,
         611,
         613,
         632,
         633,
         634,
         635,
         636,
         637,
         865,
         870,
         900,
         910,
         950,
         951,
         952,
         953,
         954,
         955,
         999,
         1045,
         1046,
         1521,
         1522,
         1525,
         1526,
         1531,
         1532
        )
      ) 
    ORDER BY 
      "products_displayproductaccess"."product_id" ASC NULLS LAST,
      "products_displayproductaccess"."price" DESC NULLS FIRST,
      "products_displayproductaccess"."is_instock" DESC NULLS FIRST
) as subquery
ORDER BY subquery.price DESC NULLS FIRST, subquery.is_instock DESC NULLS FIRST
LIMIT 100
```

**RESULTS - Subquery + Distinct**

```
"Limit  (cost=272865.00..272865.25 rows=100 width=719) (actual time=1087.171..1087.184 rows=100 loops=1)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=272865.00..272936.34 rows=28534 width=719) (actual time=1087.170..1087.175 rows=100 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: subquery.price DESC, subquery.is_instock DESC"
"        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 95kB"
"        ->  Subquery Scan on subquery  (cost=23.32..271774.45 rows=28534 width=719) (actual time=0.031..1067.073 rows=51147 loops=1)"
"              ->  Unique  (cost=23.32..271489.11 rows=28534 width=723) (actual time=0.029..1057.363 rows=51147 loops=1)"
"                    ->  Merge Join  (cost=23.32..266823.74 rows=1866147 width=723) (actual time=0.029..976.558 rows=1866146 loops=1)"
"                          Merge Cond: (products_displayproductaccess.product_id = products_displayproduct.id)"
"                          ->  Merge Append  (cost=0.56..240512.03 rows=1866147 width=11) (actual time=0.016..714.280 rows=1866146 loops=1)"
"                                Sort Key: products_displayproductaccess.product_id, products_displayproductaccess.price DESC, products_displayproductaccess.is_instock DESC"
"                                ->  Index Scan using products_displayproductaccess_idx_highest_priced on products_displayproductaccess  (cost=0.12..2.29 rows=1 width=11) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=1)"
"                                      Filter: ((location_intspace = 755) AND (location_id = ANY ('{55,60,61,62,64,65,68,69,72,78,79,81,84,85,89,92,97,99,101,102,113,120,121,130,149,187,210,234,597,599,601,602,603,605,606,607,608,610,611,613,632,633,634,635,636,637,865,870,900,910,950,951,952,953,954,955,999,1045,1046,1521,1522,1525,1526,1531,1532}'::integer[])))"
"                                ->  Index Scan using test_1_idx on products_displayproductaccess_755_755  (cost=0.43..221848.26 rows=1866146 width=11) (actual time=0.013..627.617 rows=1866146 loops=1)"
"                                      Filter: ((location_intspace = 755) AND (location_id = ANY ('{55,60,61,62,64,65,68,69,72,78,79,81,84,85,89,92,97,99,101,102,113,120,121,130,149,187,210,234,597,599,601,602,603,605,606,607,608,610,611,613,632,633,634,635,636,637,865,870,900,910,950,951,952,953,954,955,999,1045,1046,1521,1522,1525,1526,1531,1532}'::integer[])))"
"                          ->  Index Scan using products_displayproduct_pkey on products_displayproduct  (cost=0.29..2877.23 rows=52045 width=712) (actual time=0.009..36.709 rows=52045 loops=1)"
"Planning Time: 17.100 ms"
"Execution Time: 1087.231 ms"
```

**Attempt #2 (wrong results - excellent execution time) - no subquery with distinct. This is very close to the performance and results we're hoping for. Postgres can simply walk the combined index because it's in the exact same order as the order by statement. The problem is there will be duplicate rows when the price on the products_displayproductaccess table varies for example. I simply don't know how to wrap this in say a function that can take 50 rows at a time squash the duplicates and take another 50 until it satisfies the limit and offset properly.**

```
    SELECT 
      DISTINCT ON (
          "products_displayproductaccess"."price",
          "products_displayproductaccess"."is_instock",
          "products_displayproductaccess"."product_id"
        ) 
      "products_displayproduct"."id", 
      "products_displayproduct"."date_created", 
      "products_displayproduct"."date_updated", 
      "products_displayproduct"."name", 
      "products_displayproduct"."sub_title", 
      "products_displayproduct"."tags", 
      "products_displayproduct"."has_multiple_variants", 
      "products_displayproduct"."placement_id", 
      "products_displayproduct"."brand_id", 
      "products_displayproduct"."poster_image_id", 
      "products_displayproduct"."rating", 
      "products_displayproduct"."reviews", 
      "products_displayproduct"."is_toppick", 
      "products_displayproduct"."last_amalgamation", 
      "products_displayproduct"."search_index" 
    FROM 
      "products_displayproduct" 
      INNER JOIN "products_displayproductaccess" ON (
        "products_displayproduct"."id" = "products_displayproductaccess"."product_id"
      ) 
    WHERE 
      (
        --"products_displayproduct"."placement_id" = 853
        "products_displayproductaccess"."location_intspace" IN (755) 
        AND "products_displayproductaccess"."location_id" IN (
         55,
         60,
         61,
         62,
         64,
         65,
         68,
         69,
         72,
         78,
         79,
         81,
         84,
         85,
         89,
         92,
         97,
         99,
         101,
         102,
         113,
         120,
         121,
         130,
         149,
         187,
         210,
         234,
         597,
         599,
         601,
         602,
         603,
         605,
         606,
         607,
         608,
         610,
         611,
         613,
         632,
         633,
         634,
         635,
         636,
         637,
         865,
         870,
         900,
         910,
         950,
         951,
         952,
         953,
         954,
         955,
         999,
         1045,
         1046,
         1521,
         1522,
         1525,
         1526,
         1531,
         1532
        )
      ) 
    ORDER BY 
      "products_displayproductaccess"."price" DESC NULLS FIRST,
      "products_displayproductaccess"."is_instock" DESC NULLS FIRST,
      "products_displayproductaccess"."product_id" ASC NULLS LAST
LIMIT 100
```

**RESULTS - Walking the Index**

```
"Limit  (cost=2.77..225.27 rows=100 width=723) (actual time=0.069..2.854 rows=100 loops=1)"
"  ->  Unique  (cost=2.77..830440.99 rows=373230 width=723) (actual time=0.069..2.845 rows=100 loops=1)"
"        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=2.77..816444.89 rows=1866147 width=723) (actual time=0.067..2.647 rows=1043 loops=1)"
"              ->  Merge Append  (cost=2.48..240507.76 rows=1866147 width=11) (actual time=0.055..1.105 rows=1043 loops=1)"
"                    Sort Key: products_displayproductaccess.price DESC, products_displayproductaccess.is_instock DESC, products_displayproductaccess.product_id"
"                    ->  Sort  (cost=2.04..2.05 rows=1 width=11) (actual time=0.005..0.006 rows=0 loops=1)"
"                          Sort Key: products_displayproductaccess.price DESC, products_displayproductaccess.is_instock DESC, products_displayproductaccess.product_id"
"                          Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB"
"                          ->  Index Scan using products_displayproductaccess_product_id_2a2032ac on products_displayproductaccess  (cost=0.12..2.03 rows=1 width=11) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=1)"
"                                Filter: ((location_intspace = 755) AND (location_id = ANY ('{55,60,61,62,64,65,68,69,72,78,79,81,84,85,89,92,97,99,101,102,113,120,121,130,149,187,210,234,597,599,601,602,603,605,606,607,608,610,611,613,632,633,634,635,636,637,865,870,900,910,950,951,952,953,954,955,999,1045,1046,1521,1522,1525,1526,1531,1532}'::integer[])))"
"                    ->  Index Scan using test_2_idx on products_displayproductaccess_755_755  (cost=0.43..221844.23 rows=1866146 width=11) (actual time=0.049..1.037 rows=1043 loops=1)"
"                          Filter: ((location_intspace = 755) AND (location_id = ANY ('{55,60,61,62,64,65,68,69,72,78,79,81,84,85,89,92,97,99,101,102,113,120,121,130,149,187,210,234,597,599,601,602,603,605,606,607,608,610,611,613,632,633,634,635,636,637,865,870,900,910,950,951,952,953,954,955,999,1045,1046,1521,1522,1525,1526,1531,1532}'::integer[])))"
"              ->  Index Scan using products_displayproduct_pkey on products_displayproduct  (cost=0.29..0.31 rows=1 width=712) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=1043)"
"                    Index Cond: (id = products_displayproductaccess.product_id)"
"Planning Time: 14.706 ms"
"Execution Time: 2.915 ms"
```

**NIKITA's ANSWER (30k stack exchange char limit exceeded)**
https://pastebin.com/SP5fQq9F

EDIT:

**NIKITAS'S ANSWER #2 (updated)**
Query: https://pastebin.com/raw/hGRVcPJb
Explain Analyze: https://pastebin.com/raw/iS1KxDsH

Comment: *General Note:* Comments not asking for clarification or suggesting improvements to the question have been removed. Anyone wanting to propose a solution should use the answer box.

Comment: now execution plan looks better but I sill see these heap lookups, could you please show testidx2? it looks like it doesn't include location_id.

Comment: Why the restriction "without using a subquery"? If there is a way to solve your issue super fast with a subquery, what is the objection?

Comment: Please remember to *always* provide your version of Postgres. Especially essential since partitioning is involved, which has performance issues in Postgres 10 and (to a lesser degree) Postgres 11. And how did you implement partitioning *exactly*? Doesn't look like [declarative partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html), yet? Also, what's the role of the commented clause `-- "products_displayproduct"."placement_id" = 853`?

Comment: We're using Postgres 11, 12 in the near future. The placement is the sub category the product is placed in. We also have a search_index ts vector we would like to query against along with the other conditions on access, like in stock. DDL Partitioning is something we could do if it made a difference, the tables are generated by Django. Newer releases to support it, we're coming from an older one that build partitions with triggers.

Comment: We updated to PG12, for DDL native partitioning. Performance is improved but the query is still not perfect. I really do not understand why it's so difficult to just get 1 row for the leftmost table from the JOIN, with a different order by than the DISTINCT ON clause. The subquery kills performance, walking the two table's indexes that match the order by exactly, then joining seems like the fastest approach. Tried lateral, very bad performance with no conditions on products_displayproduct. https://paste.depesz.com/s/8dr https://explain.depesz.com/s/g9VJP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexes or partitions won't help you much, because you are reading and sorting 1866147 rows from the join in the inner query, and the LIMIT 100 in the outer query cannot be pushed down to the inner query because, as you noted, there will be duplicate rows when the price on the products_displayproductaccess table varies.
Your second attempt is fast because of the limit, not because of the index.

The trick is to use what you know of your data that the query optimizer cannot know.

How many prices can you have in a single location for the same product?
If any product can have only one price in a single location, and you need 100 products from a list of 65 locations (as in your example) then the maximum number of different prices you need from the inner query is 100*65=6500 rows. Any other record would be discarded even if all products had different prices in every location.
If you add LIMIT 6500 (or LIMIT 10000) to the inner query, it's still a lot less than 1866147 rows and it should run much faster.

So, start with the query in your second attempt, using a wider limit of 6500 rows, and then restrict it to 100 rows using distinct on product_id.

Can you try this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (  
       subquery."product_id"
        ),
       subquery.*
FROM (
    SELECT 
      DISTINCT ON (
          "products_displayproductaccess"."price",
          "products_displayproductaccess"."is_instock",
          "products_displayproductaccess"."product_id"
        ) 
      "products_displayproduct"."id", 
      "products_displayproduct"."date_created", 
      "products_displayproduct"."date_updated", 
      "products_displayproduct"."name", 
      "products_displayproduct"."sub_title", 
      "products_displayproduct"."tags", 
      "products_displayproduct"."has_multiple_variants", 
      "products_displayproduct"."placement_id", 
      "products_displayproduct"."brand_id", 
      "products_displayproduct"."poster_image_id", 
      "products_displayproduct"."rating", 
      "products_displayproduct"."reviews", 
      "products_displayproduct"."is_toppick", 
      "products_displayproduct"."last_amalgamation", 
      "products_displayproduct"."search_index" 
    FROM 
      "products_displayproduct" 
      INNER JOIN "products_displayproductaccess" ON (
        "products_displayproduct"."id" = "products_displayproductaccess"."product_id"
      ) 
    WHERE 
      (
        --"products_displayproduct"."placement_id" = 853
        "products_displayproductaccess"."location_intspace" IN (755) 
        AND "products_displayproductaccess"."location_id" IN (
         55,
         60,
         61,
         62,
         64,
         65,
         68,
         69,
         72,
         78,
         79,
         81,
         84,
         85,
         89,
         92,
         97,
         99,
         101,
         102,
         113,
         120,
         121,
         130,
         149,
         187,
         210,
         234,
         597,
         599,
         601,
         602,
         603,
         605,
         606,
         607,
         608,
         610,
         611,
         613,
         632,
         633,
         634,
         635,
         636,
         637,
         865,
         870,
         900,
         910,
         950,
         951,
         952,
         953,
         954,
         955,
         999,
         1045,
         1046,
         1521,
         1522,
         1525,
         1526,
         1531,
         1532
        )
      ) 
    ORDER BY 
      "products_displayproductaccess"."price" DESC NULLS FIRST,
      "products_displayproductaccess"."is_instock" DESC NULLS FIRST,
      "products_displayproductaccess"."product_id" ASC NULLS LAST
    LIMIT 6500) as subquery
ORDER BY 
      "products_displayproductaccess"."price" DESC NULLS FIRST,
      "products_displayproductaccess"."is_instock" DESC NULLS FIRST,
      "products_displayproductaccess"."product_id" ASC NULLS LAST
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: I just realized that this question was asked more than 2 years ago..

Answer (score 2):

The working query you *have*, should get substantially faster if you do `ORDER BY` / `LIMIT` *before* the join:

```
SELECT p.id
     , p.date_created
     , p.date_updated
     , p.name
     , p.sub_title
     , p.tags
     , p.has_multiple_variants
     , p.placement_id
     , p.brand_id
     , p.poster_image_id
     , p.rating
     , p.reviews
     , p.is_toppick
     , p.last_amalgamation
     , p.search_index
     , pa.price
     , pa.is_instock
FROM  (
   SELECT *
   FROM  (
      SELECT DISTINCT ON (product_id)
             product_id, price, is_instock
      FROM   products_displayproductaccess
      WHERE  location_intspace = 755
      AND    location_id IN (55, 60, 61, 1532)  -- many more
      ORDER  BY product_id, price DESC, is_instock DESC
      ) sub
   ORDER  BY price DESC, is_instock DESC
   LIMIT  100
   ) pa
JOIN   products_displayproduct p ON p.id = pa.product_id;
```

Depending on data distribution and typical query predicates, `DISTINCT ON` in the subquery might be replaced with something more efficient. Maybe a recursive CTE or a `LATERAL` join to a subquery with `ORDER BY`  / `LIMIT`. See:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25536748/939860)
- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860)
- [Postgres sometimes uses inferior index for WHERE a IN (...) ORDER BY b LIMIT N](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/249617/postgres-sometimes-uses-inferior-index-for-where-a-in-order-by-b-limit-n)
- [Can spatial index help a "range - order by - limit" query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18300/can-spatial-index-help-a-range-order-by-limit-query)

And there is probably more potential to make this faster, yet. Looks like a major project for paid consultant work - starting by sanitizing your table partitioning. The undisclosed triggers `after_insert_products_displayproductaccess_trigger` and `before_insert_products_displayproductaccess_trigger` look like a sub-optimal implementation.

Comment: Just realized that Nikita already suggests a very similar query. Leaving the post for the additional details.

Comment: So the problem with this query is it doesn't leave room for any conditions on products_displayproduct... We have a placement_id for product placement and a tsvector column for text searches.

Comment: I asked about the commented clause `-- "products_displayproduct"."placement_id" = 853` above, but no response. And `search_index` wasn't mentioned as part of the `WHERE` clause. Both make a difference ...

Comment: Hi Erwin, I do apologize for not getting a response to you sooner about that condition before the query was optimized. I've been super busy... It is an important condition as is being able to use the search_index field with ts_queries.

Comment: This isn't exact, if we add condition to the join like placement_id, the results are incorrect.

Comment: All the ordering back and forth (even though there are indexes that match each one exactly) yields slow performance, > 4,000ms on an i7 @ 4.2 GHZ + NVME SSD. Query: https://paste.depesz.com/s/JsV8 Explain: https://explain.depesz.com/s/YpLR

Answer (score 1):

did you try this?:

```
create index ix_products_displayproductaccess_location_intspace_product_id_etc 
    on products_displayproductaccess (location_intspace, product_id, price desc, is_instock desc) 
    include (location_id);

select product_id, price, is_instock 
from (
       select distinct on (product_id) product_id, price, is_instock 
       from products_displayproductaccess 
       where products_displayproductaccess.location_intspace IN (755) 
              and products_displayproductaccess.location_id IN (55, 60,...) 
       order by product_id, price desc, is_instock desc
      ) as subq 
order by price desc, is_instock desc, product_id limit 100;

select id as product_id, price, is_instock
from products_displayproduct
inner join lateral (select price, is_instock 
      from products_displayproductaccess
      where products_displayproductaccess.product_id = products_displayproduct.id
         and products_displayproductaccess.location_id IN (55, 60,...)  
       order by price desc, is_instock desc
       limit 1)
order by price desc, is_instock desc, product_id limit 100;
```

UPDATED
New idea:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_test ON products_displayproductaccess (location_id, location_intspace, price desc, is_instock desc, product_id);

WITH conditions AS (
    SELECT location_intspace, location_id 
    FROM
        (SELECT UNNEST(STRING_TO_ARRAY('753,754,755,756,757', ',')) AS location_intspace) a
    CROSS JOIN
        (SELECT UNNEST(STRING_TO_ARRAY('1031,1032,1033,1034,1035', ',')) AS location_id) b
)
,products AS (
SELECT DISTINCT ON (product_id) product_id, price, is_instock
FROM conditions
INNER JOIN LATERAL(
                   SELECT price, is_instock, product_id
                   FROM products_displayproductaccess
                   WHERE location_id = conditions.location_id AND location_intspace = conditions.location_intspace 
                   ORDER BY price DESC, is_instock DESC, product_id LIMIT 100
                   ) AS L ON true
ORDER BY product_id, price DESC, is_instock DESC;
)
SELECT product_id, price, is_instock
FROM products
ORDER BY price DESC, is_instock DESC, product_id LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this on our new Postgresql 12 installation. The performance is extremely poor because of the sub query. Query: https://paste.depesz.com/s/F3g Explain: https://explain.depesz.com/s/usyna

See above for the lateral, also very very slow.

Comment: @KevinParker attached query differs from the original one, now you use more complex condition: "products_displayproductaccess"."location_intspace" IN (753, 754, 755, 756, 757)

Comment: It's pretty much the same though, the instpace just lets postgress know which partitions to select from. Also the location_intspace is included in the index anyways. Filtering on a child table only makes very little difference in terms of performance, the problem is the structure of the query needs excessive, just to find distinct with a different order by, that postgres cannot simply walk the indexes of the two tables with lateral or a subquery.

Comment: @KevinParker additional sort is added because of this condition (line #4 in explain output), for lateral query it makes things even worse

Comment: Yes it does... Find results in two tables with conditions on each, walk indexs, join, one row per left most table, sorted, limit, offset. Without 3 layers of sorts or subqueries I'm just incredibly surprised at how difficult something so seemingly common is on postgres. True experts Laurenz / Erwin, happy pay $500 USD for the right solution (will provide dump). Tempted to throw this up a Maria DB instance and see how this could be done, some missing features like RETURNING were recently implemented, but partitioning support is worse: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/partitioning-limitations/

Comment: @KevinParker for modified query please test this index: create index ix_test on products_displayproductaccess (product_id, price desc, is_instock desc) include (location_id, location_intspace);

Comment: this difficulty is caused not by postgres, it is not possible to pre-sort every subset of rows you may want to select and your subsets are large (contains million of rows)

Comment: @KevinParker, I updated the answer with new solution

Comment: So I tried the updated query and it didn't work, I had to modify it but my postgres knowledge is far from perfect (as you can see). It doesn't seem right to do a lateral join with 100 rows, maybe it's just supposed to be a left join?

Query (probably wrong): https://paste.depesz.com/s/HP6
Explain: https://explain.depesz.com/s/YcaX

Comment: @KevinParker I fixed syntax. Please check the results. It is correct to select limit 100 in lateral join because we select top 100 products by price for each location and after that we need to sort much smaller amount of rows to find top 100 products over all locations. In your example you forgot to add ORDER BY at the end of the query.

Comment: I just tried and believe me I wish this would work, maybe someone from the postgres team can shed some light on making distinct on work with other order by's... 
ERROR:  SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions. LINE 8: SELECT DISTINCT ON (product_id) product_id, price, is_instoc...

Comment: @KevinParker, I specialize in SQL Server and MySQL but I really want to make this query work :) I updated the query, it should work correctly now.

Answer (score 1):

`products_displayproduct` doesn't seem to be so big, so I would aim for a hash join with an index only scan on `products_displayproductaccess_755_755`:

```
CREATE INDEX ON products_displayproductaccess (location_intspace, location_id)
   INCLUDE (price, is_instock, product_id);

VACUUM products_displayproductaccess_755_755;
```

For older versions of PostgreSQL that don't support the `INCLUDE` clause, add the columns to the index keys. For older PostgreSQL versions that don't support partitioned indexes, index the partition.

Comment: such index is already exists - "pmtest" btree (location_intspace, location_id) INCLUDE (product_id, price, is_instock)

Comment: Did you `VACUUM` the table?

Comment: Yes. Table has been VACUUM ANALYZE FULL on the master table and partitioned natively on PG 12. Tried various queries, the only one that has even close performance for a web app is this one, Query: https://paste.depesz.com/s/uWT Explain: https://explain.depesz.com/s/PZKv but the distinct needs to match the order by and it returns duplicates. I'm struggling with how difficult this is in PG12 or is it just me?