# Can you paginate through 2 tables in parallel, with 1 query

Tags: postgresql, union, pagination

I want to paginate through 2 different sources.
I think I can do this using the thing where u join 2 queries into one, however, I don't want to merge them in parallel.

Is it possible to select the size of the first query, so I can limit the size of the  second query; allowing me to properly paginate; first through the first query; and if partial / no result; then paginate through the second query.

I could obviously implement this at my application level, but I would prefer a single query.

---

After thinking about it, I could maybe do something like this?

```sql
with a as (... offset :offset limit :limit), 
    a_count as (select count(*) from a)
    select * a 
    union
    select ...
    offset (select count from a_count)
    limit greatest(:limit - (select count from a_count), 0)
```

Is this efficient? What can I improve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply:

```
SELECT 'a' AS source, * FROM a
UNION ALL                         -- NOT just UNION!!
SELECT 'b' AS source, * FROM b    -- matching row type!
OFFSET :offset
LIMIT  :limit;
```

The added `source` is optional.

Unless using parentheses, `LIMIT` / `OFFSET` apply to the combined result set. While combined with `UNION ALL`, and no outer `ORDER BY`, you get rows from table `a` first, and rows from table `b` next.

If you need a particular sort order, add `ORDER BY` per table with parentheses. Like:

```
(SELECT * FROM a ORDER BY foo)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM b ORDER BY bar)
OFFSET :offset
LIMIT  :limit;
```

Still no outer `ORDER BY`!

**However**, `LIMIT` / `OFFEST` for pagination scales terribly for big tables. Consider instead:

- [Efficient pagination for big tables](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/219782/efficient-pagination-for-big-tables/219810#219810)
- [Optimize query with OFFSET on large table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34291099/939860)

Comment: Thanks for this, I didn't realise how much I overcomplicated the query. And also the union all tip

Comment: Do you know how you would filter duplicates, will maintaining the same order

Comment: @Tobi: Please ask your new question as *question* (with the necessary details). Comments are not the place. You can always link to this one for context.